# MySQL stored procedure with if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure in MySQL

```
SELECT *
    FROM rewards
        LEFT JOIN tasks
        ON tasks.id = rewards.task_id
        AND rewards.received_at = received_Date
    WHERE tasks.kid_id = kid_Id
    ORDER BY tasks.id ASC;
```

The stored procedure has 2 (IN) inputs, `kid_Id` (integer) and `received_Date` (date), and it works fine.

**Question:** What I want is if the `received_Date` is `NULL` then I want to view all dates, is that possible?

Say in other words:

the `AND rewards.received_at = received_Date` should only work if I pass `received_Date` otherwise return all dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use `OR` operator in `where clause` to get all the rows if `received_Date is null`

```
SELECT *
    FROM rewards
        LEFT JOIN tasks
        ON tasks.id = rewards.task_id
                WHERE tasks.kid_id = kid_Id 
                AND (rewards.received_at = received_Date or received_Date = 0) 
    ORDER BY tasks.id ASC;
```